# CTP5 update cascade

Tags: c#, entity-framework, entity-framework-ctp5

I need an Add or Update pattern for CTP5.
Assuming the model:

```
public class User
{
    public int UserId { get; set; }
    public ICollection<Address> Addresses { get; set; }
}
public class Address
{
    public int AddressID { get; set; }
    public string Location { get; set; }
}
```

If I add a new User, The coresponding Address table is also populated.
But if the user is already in DB, I will get an DbUpdateException. In this case I want the data in the database to be updated with the new data. How can I do this?

data in database

Table Address

AddressID        Location

1                JohnPlace

2                MaryPlace

3                JimmyPlace

The User I update has in the Addresses collection 1 item with AddressId:2, Location=GeorgePlace.
But for ID=2, in the Db there is already a record with location=MarryPlace. I want GeorgePlace to overwrite MarryPlace.

I cannot have an address that is not assigned to a user

I create a user like:

```
var user=new User();
user.Id=GetUserIDfromService();
foreach(var address in GetAddressesFromService(user.Id)){
    user.Addresses.Add(address);
}
context.Users.Add(user);
context.SaveChanges();//this may throw an exception, because there is already a user with this id.
```

Comment: @Ryan: So you can have address in database which isn't assigned to any user? Can you also post your update code?

Comment: I do something like Jakub Konecki suggested. But I would like to be able to do something like context.Users.Add(newUser); context.SaveChanges()

Comment: @Ryan: Post your code. We need to know how did you receive / created user and address object you want to update as well as your actual update method.

Comment: @Ryan: What is GetAddressFromService doing? Is it loading addresses from DB on other context instance?

Comment: no , it gets data from a webservice

Answer (score 0):

If you want to update an existing user do not insert it (do not call `Add()`)
Load the user by Id first than modify it's properties and call `SaveChanges()` on the context.

```
var db = new DatabaseContext();
var user = db.Users.Find(myUserId);
user.Name = "New Name";
db.SaveChanges();
```

Comment: yes but this would require me to do the same for each address, than also for the user. Some addresses would be new, so I need to Add them, some would need update

Answer (score 0):

Your current problem is that you prepare new User object and fills its addresses but addresses are not loaded from DB via same context so context don't know them. When you call Add method it will take all objects in object graph and marks them as new (to be inserted). The only way to avoid this is manually say which Address is new and which is only modification or load addresses from context before you add them to User instance.

The code for marking addresses can look like:

```
var user = new User(); 
user.Id = GetUserIDfromService(); 
context.Users.Add(user); 
foreach(var address in GetAddressesFromService(user.Id))
{
  context.Addresses.Attach(address);
  // Let say that new address always have 0 Id      
  context.Entry(address).State = address.Id == 0 ? EntityState.Added : EntityState.Modified;      
  user.Addresses.Add(address); 
} 

context.SaveChanges();
```

Comment: I may already have an address with the Id I am adding. Unfortunatelly I cannot assume that new addresses are 0. My solution is to try to add the User as new, than to catch the DbUpdateException if it occures, and in the catch block I add it as modified. What do you think?

Comment: @Ryan: That looks like similar problem to this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5024094/how-can-i-ignore-a-dbupdateconcurrencyexception-with-my-entity-framework-code I'm personally against these solutions because if you work with entities without knowledge if they are new or modified something strange is happening in your application. It will generally work but it will process failures one by one, so I expect that for 20 addresses which should be modified you will have to catch exception 20 times.

Comment: How do you suggest I should implement this someway else?

Comment: @Ryan: If you don't know if address is new or not you should try to load it first.

Comment: I tought of doing that, but I considered the exception handling would be easier. If I first try to load, than add I have 2 Db operations for each address. If I use exceptions, I have 1Db op if data is new, and 2DbOp+1exception if address is already in. Thanks for your replies. Do you think I made the right decision by using exception handling, or I should first load the data?

Comment: @Ryan: You can use single query which will load all possible addresses returned from GetAddressesFrom service. Linq to entities allows equivalent of IN operator in SQL (contains). So you can pass all addresses Ids to the single query.

Comment: This sounds as exactly what I would need. Could you give me an example.Thanks alot!

Comment: @Ryan: Check here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2714681/how-to-use-in-operator-in-linq You must create collection of addresses Ids and use something like: `from address in context.Addresses where ids.Contains(address.Id) select address`